# Iterate over string fragments

Tags: c++

I've got lua path, e.g.:

```
"/home/user/?.lua;/home/test/?/init.lua;./lua"
```

I want to iterate over every fragment (`/home/user/?.lua`, `/home/test/?/init.lua` and `./lua` in example). My attempt doesn't work correctly for some reasons:

```
size_t begin = 0;
size_t next = searchpath.find_first_of(";", 0);
do
{
    if (next == std::string::npos)
        next = searchpath.length();
    std::string prefix = searchpath.substr(begin, next);
    std::cout << "Trying: " << prefix << "\n";
    begin = next + 1;
    next = searchpath.find_first_of(";", begin);
} while (begin < (int)searchpath.length());
```

Output:

```
Trying: /home/v/.luarocks/share/lua/5.2/?.lua
Trying: /home/v/.luarocks/share/lua/5.2/?/init.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.2/?.lua;/usr/share/l
Trying: /usr/share/lua/5.2/?.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.2/?/init.lua;/usr/local/share/lua/5.2/?.lua;/usr/local/share/lu
Trying: /usr/share/lua/5.2/?/init.lua;/usr/local/share/lua/5.2/?.lua;/usr/local/share/lua/5.2/?/init.lua;/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/?.lua;/usr/loca
Trying: /usr/local/share/lua/5.2/?.lua;/usr/local/share/lua/5.2/?/init.lua;/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/?.lua;/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/?/init.lua;./?.lua;/home/v/.lua/libs/?.lua;/hom
Trying: /usr/local/share/lua/5.2/?/init.lua;/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/?.lua;/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/?/init.lua;./?.lua;/home/v/.lua/libs/?.lua;/home/v/.lua/libs/?.lua;./lib/?.lua;./lib/?/init.lua
Trying: /usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/?.lua;/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/?/init.lua;./?.lua;/home/v/.lua/libs/?.lua;/home/v/.lua/libs/?.lua;./lib/?.lua;./lib/?/init.lua
Trying: /usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/?/init.lua;./?.lua;/home/v/.lua/libs/?.lua;/home/v/.lua/libs/?.lua;./lib/?.lua;./lib/?/init.lua
Trying: ./?.lua;/home/v/.lua/libs/?.lua;/home/v/.lua/libs/?.lua;./lib/?.lua;./lib/?/init.lua
Trying: /home/v/.lua/libs/?.lua;/home/v/.lua/libs/?.lua;./lib/?.lua;./lib/?/init.lua
Trying: /home/v/.lua/libs/?.lua;./lib/?.lua;./lib/?/init.lua
Trying: ./lib/?.lua;./lib/?/init.lua
```

Can you explain me, please, what is wrong with my code and what is correct way?

Comment: I'd use `std::getline()` which takes an optional `delim` argument.

Comment: can you please explain what is the output of your code and why it is wrong? `...` isnt something that I can compile to reproduce your results. See also [mcve]

Comment: https://github.com/moteus/lua-split#eachstr-sep-plain

Comment: Not sure this deserves a Lua tag, this could apply to any string

Comment: Why are you casting `searchpath.length()` to `int`, and then comparing it to a `size_t`.  Just get rid of the cast

Comment: @YSC I already have got variable, isn't is too hard for this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is:

```
    std::string prefix = searchpath.substr(begin, next);
```

[`std::string::substr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) takes offset + count arguments, not start + end arguments.

You need:

```
    std::string prefix = searchpath.substr(begin, next-begin);
```

So in full:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string searchpath = "a;b;c";
    size_t begin = 0;
    size_t next = searchpath.find_first_of(";", 0);
    do
    {
        if (next == std::string::npos)
            next = searchpath.length();
        std::string prefix = searchpath.substr(begin, next-begin);
        std::cout << "Trying: " << prefix << "\n";
        begin = next + 1;
        next = searchpath.find_first_of(";", begin);
    } while (begin < (int)searchpath.length());
}
```

(Note, that is what your question should have looked like.  A complete program.)

I would actually write as:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string searchpath = "a;b;c";
    for (size_t begin = 0, next; begin < searchpath.length(); begin = next+1)
    {
        next = searchpath.find(';', begin);
        if (next == std::string::npos)
            next = searchpath.length();
        std::string prefix = searchpath.substr(begin, next-begin);
        std::cout << "Trying: " << prefix << "\n";
    }
}
```

Which has less repetition, localizes begin and next to the loop, uses `find` not `find_first_of`, and doesn't have an unnecessary cast.

Answer (score 1):

Just in addition to @Martin Bonner 's answer.

Its could be done easier and more readable in my opinion, check it out.

```
char someInput[] = "/home/user/?.lua;/home/test/?/init.lua;./lua";

std::string searchpath(someInput);
std::string temp;
std::size_t pos = std::string::npos;

pos = searchpath.find(";");
while (pos != std::string::npos)
{
    temp = searchpath.substr(0, pos);
    searchpath = searchpath.substr(pos + 1);
    pos = searchpath.find(";");

    std::cout << "Trying: " << temp << std::endl;
}
std::cout << searchpath << std::endl;
```

Output

```
Trying: /home/user/?.lua
Trying: /home/test/?/init.lua
Trying: ./lua
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, but I souldn't modify `searchpath`.

Comment: As i indicated, you can just create copy of it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, the simple version using [std::getline()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline):

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::istringstream input{"/home/user/?.lua;/home/test/?/init.lua;./lua"};
    for (std::string prefix ; std::getline(input, prefix, ';') ; ) {
        std::cout << "Trying: " << prefix << "\n";
    }
}
```

<kbd>[demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d1c6f64d46011b1a)</kbd>

**Output**:

> Trying: /home/user/?.lua
>   Trying: /home/test/?/init.lua
>   Trying: ./lua